# What is the difference between “turning point” and “tipping point?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I was under impression that “turning point” and “tipping point” are basically saying the same thing in that both words refer to big change of movement, trend and situation allowing no-return. But when I come across the following statement in Washington Post’s (August 21) article that came under the title, “The elite strikes back- getting under Trump’s skin,” I felt like there is a significant difference between two phrases.

> The past week has been **a turning point, perhaps even a tipping point.**
>   Since the President abdicated his moral leadership after
>   Charlottesville, the well-connected have used their leverage to send a
>   message about what truly makes America great.

I checked online Oxford Dictionary. It defines “turning point” as:
The point at which a decisive change in a situation occurs, **especially one with beneficial results.**

And “tipping point” as:
The point at which a series of small changes or incidents becomes significant enough to cause a large, more important change.

Here's my questions:

Is turning point always directed to “beneficial result” as Online Oxford Dictionary defines in contrast the direction or result of “tipping point being neutral or negative?

Comment: Neither term is necessarily "beneficial".

Comment: @Hot Licks. I thought so either. But Online Oxford Dictionary defines otherwise by articulating "especially with beneficial results." Who is right?

Comment: "Especially", in this context, doesn't mean "certainly".

Answer (score 3):

Both of these terms are figurative usages, so it helps to look at the literal origins of each.

From *OED*:

**Turning point**

Definition 2 is the figurative use being used by the writer here.

> **2**. *fig[urative]* A point at which a decisive change of any kind takes place; a critical point, crisis.

The literal origin is in definition 1:

> **1**. *lit[eral]* A point at which something turns, or changes its direction of motion, etc.; spec. a maximum or minimum point on a graph, where it begins to tend downwards or upwards.

Just as a point where something literally turns doesn't carry either a positive or negative connotation, the figurative use *turning point* simply means a figurative point where events or consequences turn, which could be for either better or worse.

*Oxford Dictionary*'s reference to *"especially one with beneficial results"* is not mentioned in *OED*, but it could be a reflection of usage frequency.  The term is often used in phrases with a positive or hopeful connotation.

> It was a real *turning-point* in his career. [This would usually mean a positive change, but it could mean either, depending on context.]

**Tipping point**

*Tipping point* is a much more recent term, attested as recently as 1957 by *OED*, whereas *turning point* was attested as early as 1836.  The definition provided is only a draft edition according to the online edition. In the *Washington Post* article, as in this definition, the phrase is a figurative reference to the literal meaning, a point at which something physically *tips over*, marking a decisive change, and possibly a destructive or disruptive one.  Imagine a ledge tipping over from weight, or a less destructive analogy: adding weights to a balance, one by one, until it tips in the other direction.

[image]

> tipping point  n. the prevalence of a social phenomenon sufficient to set in motion a process of rapid change; the moment when such a change begins to occur.

This sense doesn't necessarily have a negative connotation, but because it signals a more abrupt and dramatic change, it can have a connotation of *disruption*.